# Is it ok to use RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request in production?

Tags: spring, grails, request

Does `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request` has any performance impact? I know that this is not good to access request inside service methods but I really need it. So if I call `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request` 20-30 times per request does it slow down performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not related to perfomance. Ipotetically a service method can be called outside of a request (for example in a quartz scheduled job). Probably in this case RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request will throw an exception. The best way I think is to pass the request as parameter to service method that need it.

```
class MyService{

def method(def request){
    //do what you want with the request
}

}
```

And from a controller

```
class MyController{

def myService

def index = { 

   myService.method(request)

}

}
```